# Trying to implement isotope.js in react website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jquery-isotope

I've just started learning React and I have a dummy portfolio page where I want to implement isotope.js filtering.
I am using refs to refer to the DOM node and then initialize the plugin under componentDidMount().

My code is given below :

```
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
    import Header from './Components/Header';
    import Footer from './Components/Footer';
    import Breadcrumb from './Components/Breadcrumb';
    import PortfolioItem from './Components/PortfolioItem';
    import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';
    import PortfolioData from './portoflio.json';
    import $ from 'jquery';

    class Portfolio extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.portGridRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        
        var portfolioGrid = this.portGridRef.current;
    
        $(portfolioGrid).isotope();
        $('#portfolio-flters li').on('click', function() {
         $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
           $(this).addClass('filter-active');

          portfolioIsotope.isotope({
            filter: $(this).data('filter')
         });
        });

    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
    
                <Header/>
    
                <main id="main">
    
                    <Breadcrumb currentPage="Portfolio"/>
    
                    <section id="portfolio" className="portfolio">
    
                            <div className="container">
    
                                <div className="section-title">
    
                                    <h2>Our Portfolio</h2>
    
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="row"  >
                                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                                    <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                                        <li data-filter="*" className="filter-active">All</li>
                                        <li data-filter=".filter-app">App</li>
                                        <li data-filter=".filter-card">Card</li>
                                        <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        
                                <div className="row portfolio-container" ref={this.portGridRef}>
    
                                    {
                                        PortfolioData.map((currentItem, index) => {
                                           return  <PortfolioItem key={index} title={currentItem.title} category={currentItem.category} image={currentItem.image} />
                                        })
                                    }
                                    
                                </div>
                        
    
                            </div>
    
                        </section>
    
                    </main>
    
                <Footer/>
    
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

What I am getting -

> TypeError:
> jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).isotope is not a
> function

Can anyone help me out?